# Select every ten steps SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table:

```
----------------------------------------------
oNumber      oValue1
----------------------------------------------
1            54
2            44
3            89
4            65
ff.
10           33
11           22
ff.          
20           43
21           76
ff.          
100          45
```

I want to select every 10 value in `oNumber`. So the result should be:

```
----------------------------------------------
oNumber      oValue1
----------------------------------------------
10           33
20           43
ff.
100          45
```

Also, `oNumber` is not a sequence number. It's just a value. Even it isn't a sequence number, 10, 20, 30 and so on will always appear under `oNumber` field.

Does anyone know how is the tsql for this case?
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select * from table where oNumber % 10 = 0
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Use the ["Modulo" operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) - `%`. So in this case, the answer would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE oNumber % 10 = 0
```

This will only load if oNumber is a number divisible by ten (and therefore has a remainder zero).

Answer (score 2):

In the case you simply want multiples of 10, then just use the modulo operator as stated by Daniel and Ian.

```
select *
from table
where oNumber % 10 = 0;
```

However, I felt that you could be alluding to the fact that you want to get every 10th item in your list. If that's the case, which it may be not, you would simply just sequence your set based on `oNumber` and use the modulo operator.

```
select *
from (
    select *,
        RowNum = row_number() over (order by oNumber)
    from table) a
where RowNum % 10 = 0;
```